# Nested JSON extract first level keys and add to a column Python 3?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON type:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Big Bean Pot': [{'name': 'bacon', 'unit': 'lb', 'amount': 0.06},
{'name': 'baked beans', 'unit': 'oz', 'amount': 2.67},
{'name': 'brown sugar', 'unit': 'cup', 'amount': 0.04},
{'name': 'canned lima beans', 'unit': 'oz', 'amount': 1.25},
{'name': 'canned red kidney beans', 'unit': 'oz', 'amount': 1.25},
{'name': 'cider vinegar', 'unit': 'cup', 'amount': 0.03},
{'name': 'garlic powder', 'unit': 'teaspoon', 'amount': 0.08},
{'name': 'ground mustard', 'unit': 'teaspoon', 'amount': 0.04},
{'name': 'ketchup', 'unit': 'cup', 'amount': 0.02},
{'name': 'onions', 'unit': 'medium', 'amount': 0.25}],
'Chicken and Potatoes': [{'name': 'chicken', 'unit': 'lbs', 'amount': 0.38},
{'name': 'garlic cloves', 'unit': '', 'amount': 0.5},
{'name': 'olive oil', 'unit': 'cup', 'amount': 0.06},
{'name': 'parmesan cheese', 'unit': 'cup', 'amount': 0.19},
{'name': 'potatoes', 'unit': 'small', 'amount': 0.75},
{'name': 'salt and pepper', 'unit': 'servings', 'amount': 1.0}]}
```

I am converting the value (list of dicts) of each key with `pd.json_normalize`, so for example for `key = 'Big Bean Pot'`
I will apply `pd.json_normalize(data.get('Big Bean Pot'))` but I want the key to be one of the columns. Is there any way to add a column of `recipe_name` and put there `"Big Bean Pot"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pandas concat` :

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(value).assign(recipe=key) for key, value in data.items())
```

To set it as the first column, numpy's `np.r_` comes in handy :

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(value).assign(recipe=key) for key, value in data.items()).iloc[:, np.r_[-1, 0:3]]
```